# Select options from only one item, jquery change each

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to build a quickbuy of products with different variants in my list of products. The product has a set of avaialble options, that are collected from the select option with jQuery, passed to a input field and then submitted to the cart. The products are listed out by a loop. When I'm at the single product page it works fine, since all the option values are required.

But once in the list of products, it gets the options from all the products and passes them to all the submit fields. How can I scope a jquery function to work on only one product at a time

In the example below, I want the field to have only the values from the select options relevant to the product. Not th evalues from both product options.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".variant-selected")
    .change(function() {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).val() + ".";
      });

      $("input[name='variant']").val(str.slice(0, -1));
    })
    .trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prod1">
  <h2>
    Shirt
  </h2>
  <select class="variant-selected" name="select1">
            <option value="1" selected>Red</option>
            <option value="2">Blue</option>
            <option value="3">Green</option>
        </select>
  <select class="variant-selected" name="select2">
            <option value="A" selected>Large</option>
            <option value="B">Medium</option>
            <option value="C">Small</option>
        </select>

  <form class="addtocart">
    <input type="text" value="" name="variant">
  </form>

</div>
<div id="prod2">
  <h2>Jeans
  </h2>
  <select class="variant-selected" name="select1">
            <option value="4" selected>Orange</option>
            <option value="5">Teal</option>
            <option value="6">Forest</option>
        </select>

  <select class="variant-selected" name="select2">
        <option value="D" selected>Large</option>
        <option value="E">Medium</option>
        <option value="F">Small</option>
    </select>

  <form class="addtocart">
    <input type="text" value="" name="variant">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: i didn't understand how you know witch product have been selected tho.

Comment: you have the prod_id on hand somewhere?

Comment: yes, each product has a prod_id, but this is dynamically generated.

Comment: ok, but how do you know the client picked THAT particular product? if you have a click somewhere passing the prod_id, then just do $("select option:selected", "#prod2")

Comment: In the example above, when I select green, small under Jeans, the values are sent to both jeans and shirt, I want to be able to select for Jeans or Shirt, without them interfering with eachother

Comment: just check the parent using this.parents("div").attr("id") to grab the id, and use the id as i showed you above.

Comment: or you could use siblings too, there's a variety of ways to do it :-)

Comment: i tried, didn't work hahaha :-p

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".variant-selected")
    .change(function() {
    
      var str = "";
      var parentTag = $( this ).parent("div").attr("id");
      $("select option:selected", parentTag()).each(function() {
        str += $(this).val() + ".";
      });

      $("input[name='variant']").val(str.slice(0, -1) );
    })
    .trigger("change");
}); I tried that, but to no luck... :/

Comment: yeah, that's what i was thinking on doing.

Comment: no parentTag() only parentTag tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".variant-selected")
    .change(function() {
      var str = "";
      $(this).parent().find("select option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).val() + ".";
      });

      $(this).parent().find("input[name='variant']").val(str.slice(0, -1));
    })
    .trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prod1">
  <h2>
    Shirt
  </h2>
  <select class="variant-selected" name="select1">
            <option value="1" selected>Red</option>
            <option value="2">Blue</option>
            <option value="3">Green</option>
        </select>
  <select class="variant-selected" name="select2">
            <option value="A" selected>Large</option>
            <option value="B">Medium</option>
            <option value="C">Small</option>
        </select>

  <form class="addtocart">
    <input type="text" value="" name="variant">
  </form>

</div>
<div id="prod2">
  <h2>Jeans
  </h2>
  <select class="variant-selected" name="select1">
            <option value="4" selected>Orange</option>
            <option value="5">Teal</option>
            <option value="6">Forest</option>
        </select>

  <select class="variant-selected" name="select2">
        <option value="D" selected>Large</option>
        <option value="E">Medium</option>
        <option value="F">Small</option>
    </select>

  <form class="addtocart">
    <input type="text" value="" name="variant">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: oh the problem was in the input then, i didn't stop to think that could be it ^_^ +1

Comment: yes the problem is you was selecting all input tag with name variant but you have to select the one who is above the select that changes or in my code case, the one who is children of the parent of the select changed, its kind of counfuse to explained but the code explained by itself

Comment: Holy cow! That worked! A small edit, this.parent.find to the select option as well, and it works just like I want it ... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/83NKw/76/)